# Docker build randomly cannot resolve remote hosts

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have a Dockerfile that I am trying to build a container from, but getting unresolved host issues when attempting to run `curl` in the container.
The Dockerfile looks like:

```bash
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.3

ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=/opt/airflow

USER root
RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install vim -qqq

# install some of out required python packages
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Install gcloud tool from Ref: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/recipes.html

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-e", "-u", "-x", "-c"]

ARG CLOUD_SDK_VERSION=322.0.0
ENV GCLOUD_HOME=/home/google-cloud-sdk

ENV PATH="${GCLOUD_HOME}/bin/:${PATH}"

ENV DOWNLOAD_URL="https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-${CLOUD_SDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz" 
ENV TMP_DIR="$(mktemp -d)"
RUN curl -fL "${DOWNLOAD_URL}" --output "${TMP_DIR}/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz" 
RUN mkdir -p "${GCLOUD_HOME}" 
RUN tar xzf "${TMP_DIR}/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz" -C "${GCLOUD_HOME}" --strip-components=1 
RUN "${GCLOUD_HOME}/install.sh" \
       --bash-completion=false \
       --path-update=false \
       --usage-reporting=false \
       --quiet
RUN rm -rf "${TMP_DIR}"
RUN gcloud --version

WORKDIR $AIRFLOW_HOME

COPY scripts scripts
RUN chmod +x scripts

USER $AIRFLOW_UID
```

And during the build run, I am consistently getting an error like

```bash
docker build .
.
.
.
Step 15/24 : RUN curl -fL "${DOWNLOAD_URL}" --output "${TMP_DIR}/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz"
 ---> Running in 7dd92979e46b
+ curl -fL https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-322.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz --output '$(mktemp -d)/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dl.google.com
The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -e -u -x -c curl -fL "${DOWNLOAD_URL}" --output "${TMP_DIR}/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz"' returned a non-zero code: 6
```

(There is no problem running this `curl` command on my local computer).

OS is Ubuntu 18.04.6.
Note that my version of docker was installed via [snap](https://snapcraft.io/install/docker/ubuntu) (because was having other issues after installing docker via their official docs for Ubuntu):

```bash
sudo snap install docker
```

Also note that I was also having issues even running the `apt-get` commands in the Dockerfile and had to reinstall docker (per the SO answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1270466/760862)) in order to pass those instructions and I've had to do this multiple times (but the process fails at the curl instruction the vast majority of the time (IDK if has to do with the command itself or just that it is called later and there is some timing thing going on)). It seems apparent that it's a networking issue relating to docker, but I have no idea how to debug this.

If it matters, one thing I see during the container build process is my desktop showing a pop-up message saying "Wired Network, Connection established" then another pop-up later regarding my computer establishing connection to my actual WiFi.

Docker version:

```bash
➜ docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.14
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.15
 Git commit:        a224086349
 Built:             Thu Mar 24 17:14:32 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.14
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.15
  Git commit:       87a90dc
  Built:            Thu Mar 24 17:15:03 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.5.11
  GitCommit:        3df54a852345ae127d1fa3092b95168e4a88e2f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.3
  GitCommit:        
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

IPTables rules:

```bash
➜  airflow git:(main) ✗ sudo iptables --list              
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Trying to check connectivity via `nslookup` on the container by adding a line to the Dockerfile like

```bash
RUN apt-get install dnsutils -qqq
RUN nslookup dl.google.com
```

I get an error during build like:

```bash
Step 13/25 : RUN nslookup dl.google.com
 ---> Running in cdc6ae412569
+ nslookup dl.google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -e -u -x -c nslookup dl.google.com' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Anyone know what could be going on here or what other debugging info I can add to supplement this question?